# Co-authoring workbooks within a LAN without using an Internet connection

Tags: networking, microsoft-excel, lan, file-sharing

I have Microsoft Office 2016 Pro and I'm connected with 5 PCs through the LAN. I used Excel's "Share" for co-authoring between multiple users but there's the problem we all know about.

So, I switched to OneDrive to share the workbooks between all the PCs and it worked fine until our office Internet connection went down for a week. At that time I realised that I cannot depend on the Internet for important documents.

Then I thought about using the LAN and sharing Excel for web-edit or share but I'm not a IT guru. So I'm asking for some suggestions.

If any more details are required please let me know.

Comment: The co-authoring is strictly a feature enabled by OneDrive. You can continue to work on files in “offline” mode when the internet is down. But you will not have any co-authoring capabilities without OneDrive and an internet connection.

Comment: Check this link,,, https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin/co-authoring-on-the-local-client/a16276a3-a6c2-49bb-b797-5e2da53e9289

Answer (score -1):

We can try to set up file sharing over LAN like this：

Step1: set LAN settings:

1.Open "Network and Sharing Center->Change advanced sharing settings".

2.Expand the **Network profile** marked as **Current Profile**, select "Turn on network discovery" and " Turn on file and printer sharing".

3.Expand the **Public folder sharing**, select "Turn off password protected sharing" (the option in windows 7 operating system).

[image]

Step 2: set files or folder settings:

1. Right-click the files or folders that we want to share, select "Properties".
2. Click the "Sharing", add users or groups and set permission.

[image]

Step 3: determine the IP address of the computer where the shared files or folder we need to access.

Step 4: try to access the shared files or folder by typing the IP in step3 in another computer

We can also refer this article: [How to share files over a LAN easily using Windows 10](https://www.faqforge.com/windows/how-to-share-files-over-lan-easily-windows-10/)